# Most User Friendly Color Picker

Tags: website-design, gui-design, layout, design

I'm designing a website, and I need to allow the user to change the color of some elements. I will have to implement a color picker. What kind of color picker is the most user friendly, and looks best?

I've got four different kinds so far, but if you have another better one, please let me know.

I'm fully flexible with how the design looks.

**#1: Square Color Picker** 
[image]

**#2: Color Wheel Color Picker** 
[image]

**#3: Color Wheel - Square Color Picker** 
[image]

**#4: Color Wheel - Triangle Color Picker** 
[image]

Comment: If your users are largely familiar with a picker, you should have a design that matches that picker. For example, if most are Photoshop users, use a picker similar to Photoshop, and if most are web devs using Chrome's dev tools picker, use that.

Comment: Are you sure you need the full range of colors? I'm not sure what your use case is, but I think that most use cases can live with a much smaller subset of colors, and that would allow for a much simpler UI.

Comment: I would argue that users don't want or need that many choices to begin with.  They'll be happy to choose between 12 colors, not **16 million**.

Comment: In #4, it seems the triangle rotates to point at the selected hue. At least in a touch UI, I would expect the circle to be rotated.

Comment: Don't forget the mspaint-style one, with a rectangle with hue and saturation(?), and a separate lightness control.

Comment: Fwiw, personally I always find option 2 to suit me best. Pick the hue at a glance then adjust the intensity. Usually I'm looking for a color and the brightness is just a secondary tweak. I'd definitely add RGB or HSV text fields though so if a user already knows what color they are looking for they don't have to hunt for it. Options 3 and 4 have always confused me.

Comment: Regarding RGB values, avoid showing them as 0–255 because that’s really strange for many people and isn’t future-proof (10-bit channels). It still has to be in export formats, of course. Also, users may not want to make a predefined color more red or less green or adjust the blueness, but more magenta, less yellow or adjust the cyaness etc. That means you may want sliders that don’t represent values in any color model.

Comment: `I will have to implement a color picker` Just, for the love of Pete, use an existing color picker, don't roll your own. There are plenty of well-made, tested, refined color pickers out there.

Comment: I just want to say that I love the triangle one, the square one adds an extra variable, but the triangle one is great. Gnome3 does what some of the answers have here (have a pallete of a few colours) and it's $hit€

Comment: **Please** use the Photoshop-style square saturation/brightness with a hue slider kind if you're going to give a full color range picker. All the other types (like color wheels and square rainbow pickers) are extremely difficult and unintuitive to use. The triangle one is almost as good, and does remove the redundancy of the two black corners, but it's not as easy to adjust along a single axis.

Answer (score 88):

## Basic users first

I assume this isn't a color theory app. If this is intended to support quick color selection with a sub-set of power users, a hybrid palette chooser / builder will work well.

## Make ‘easy’ easy

Start with a palette-based chooser with reasonably sized swatches that simplifies the user's job of making a fast selection. Google has done a good job with this in Docs.

[image: Simple color swatch chooser]

#### This design benefits from three key features:

1. A reasonably broad but not overwhelming selection.
2. Thoughtful organization of options.

   1. Greyscale
   2. Bright colors
   3. Value range of the bright colors
3. A customizable section for advanced users.

That last point accommodates more particular users who are ready to put in effort with your controls to get the palette they want.

*One point of contention ...*

For the record, I think Google's base colors (the second swatch row) are useless. How many of these would you actually want in your documents without modification? Here's a quick stab at how I'd change the base color selections. It's subtle, but I think the difference is meaningful in use.

[image: A new set of base color swatches]

## Make ‘hard’ possible

You can't possibly anticipate every possible color a user may want, but you're on the right track with trying to support them. The familiar pattern (a clickable region to one side and a slider to the other) can take different forms, for better or worse.

#### Google gets this wrong.

The advanced picker model they chose lacks precision without improving usability. By using the main "stage" for hue and saturation, color selections are constrained into narrow vertical columns. Value on it's own requires very little precision but claims total ownership of the fine-grained slider control.
*Highly scientific conclusion:* I don't like it.

[image: Google's advanced color picker]

#### A better way

Dedicating the slider to hue, users can easily get to the general color they're after. The main stage is then available to fine tune saturation and value, easily creating subtle variation. This example comes from an OSX color picker plug-in I have installed on my Macs (with some modification).
*Highly scientific conclusion:* Mo betta.

[image: Modified Antetype color picker for Mac OSX]

Credit to @dberm22 for the insightful observation that this model should have the hue selector **first** to the left of the main stage. This creates a logical progression from the broad task (find the color), to the detailed (manipulate value and saturation), to the advanced (tweak or copy the numbers).

Also consider where your color values start when entering the creation state. Some pickers start with value and saturation at 0 (black) which results in a hue slider that appears to have no impact on the swatch. Starting with value and saturation somewhere in the upper right quadrant is likely to be closer to what the user wants.

## Remember the user’s hard work

However you format the control, make sure you store custom colors for users that take the time to generate them. Then they'll have a swatch library of their own over time and love your product even more!

*Credit for the "easy is easy, hard is possible" philosophy goes to Larry Wall, creator of the Perl programming language.*

Comment: +1 for showing a color picker with text edits for *all* of HSV, RGB and HEX notation. Depending on the source, only one or the other is known and conversion, though easy in principle, still takes valuable time.

Comment: I was going to post an answer saying to use the well known Microsoft Paint style chooser (very similar to the Google chooser you show) since it is the most familiar of the bunch to the masses. However, you make a great point in your comparison. 99% of the time, I put my cursor at the top edge of the main stage (fully saturated), and use the brightness on the slider. I largely ignore saturation, but if I need to go back to the main stage to adjust, I then need to re-do my brightness....

Comment: The Mac/antetype (Mo betta)  chooser fixes the above issue, but I would argue that the hue slider should be on the left since it would generally be the first thing the user adjusts.

Comment: Personally, as an advanced user, I strongly dislike the "custom color" -> "color picker" two-step approach. It always annoys me that I have to click a color switch, define the color, then select the swatch again when picking a color. But a color picker with a "recently selected color" selection, on the other hand, nice and smooth.

Comment: @JasonC as advanced users, you and I are rarely the target user for a color picker. It's typically a tertiary function in a broader app, and choosing colors is an imposing task for non-experts. The goal is to make choosing painless for the average user, but allow room for the experts.

Comment: @dberm22 That's a great point about the hue slider! It really is the logical (if not typical) order of things. I'll have to update the screen shot in the hope that our discussion may impact the state of color pickers for all!

Comment: @plainclothes Maybe, although I posit a larger argument that humans generally have the ability to learn. Perhaps choosing a color is an imposing task for a non-expert because they're used to dumbed-down interfaces, not because they can't pick colors. In addition to catering to the average, we *create* the average. It's our fault that picking a color is an imposing task, we keep oversimplifying the ui. Just clicking a button on a screen would've been imposing to somebody from 50 years ago but we persisted with the buttons and now it's basic. Break the cycle of catering to our grandparents! :)

Comment: @JasonC interesting perspective. In the right context, I think you're absolutely right! In *most* contexts, I would argue that people aren't interested in developing their understanding of color models, even if  the UI is easily learnable. They just want to grab a swatch and go. Context is everything.

Comment: Note that your suggestion (“antetype”) represents an angular / circular measure (i.e. hue) as a linear gradient; the unit is not shown so the nature of this value is intransparent to the less-knowing user, also the numeric value is positioned far away from the widget that manipulates it more visually. The square is actually a coordinate system spanned by saturation and brightness values (which should be percentages) – that is also non-obvious to the user. The red, green and blue values (which should be percentages, too) have no direct visualization but are shown the same way as HSB. Alpha?

Comment: @Crissov **1)** Strictly speaking, color is not a circular measure, it's a spectrum -- though the normal linear arrangement doesn't exactly mirror the linear wavelength distribution. **2)** Placing the numbers to the side is intentional: Very few users can manipulate color with numeric values. **3)** You can't possibly support visual manipulation of every numeric color system in a single view. **4)** Alpha transparency was not part of the OP's spec, but it could easily be added as another slider and numeric input.

Comment: @plainclothes Thanks for the answer! Am I aloud to copy, is it legal to copy the colors from the color palette and use it for my website?

Comment: @Jessica copy the colors or the color picker UI? As far as I'm concerned you can have both. There are few limits on lifting colors, but there's always a chance someone has protected a given UI (legitimately or by trolling).

Comment: @plainclothes I only want the colors. So you're saying google would allow me to do that?

Comment: @Jessica I'm not a lawyer, but I'm not sure how they'd protect that with a design patent, since that range has been around a long time. Personally, I'd rework that bright green and probably the blue next to it. The pink could use some help too.

Comment: @Jessica I updated the answer with a proposal for a new set of base swatches. If you follow Google's model, you'd also want to update the grid below them so the columns are related.

Comment: @plainclothes Thanks! Does this color palette make sense? i.imgur.com/btpBpa8.png The base colors are the same as yours. It then gets a brightness of 70% and goes down by 28 till -70%

Comment: @Jessica it's looking good. I think you could use stronger steps between the rows and some clean up with individual colors, but you're on the right track. Feel free to hit me up in chat if you're looking for more feedback.

Comment: @plainclothes I'm not sure if this is what you meant by chat, but I created a new chat room here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35302/color-palette

Answer (score 29):

I'm not sure there's any objective answer to this one, because it'll depend too much on the demographics of your clients. I'll give my subjective two cents though!

If they're not graphic designers or extremely tech-savvy, I'd want to go for the most intuitive solution, which *to me* is **the second one**. In my mind, the thoughts of a user would probably go "I want a red, maybe dark" , not "I want a dark colour, maybe red", so `Colour > Shade` works better for me than `Shade > Colour` or any of the circular ones in 3 or 4. Note that this relies on a left-to-right reading style to make sense to the user and may not work in right-to-left layouts like you'd find in Hebrew, for instance.

This reasoning may not be true, however - especially if you're picking text on a white background and you must choose a dark colour. If so, maybe horizontally flip the first one?

Additionally, I'd recommend having a bar for entering in hex codes. If you do know exactly what colour you want, it can be frustrating having to slide a selector around a large area when you could just type it in. Something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsB9vf.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Updating the graphical element updates the text immediately, and vice versa. This also is more accessible to people who can't click and drag easily, or have troubles with vision.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm trying to cater my website to tech-savvy, regular, and not at all tech-savvy people. I really appreciate what you said!

Comment: While I agree that most users would likely want to pick a hue (e.g. green) first, and then maybe tint or shade it down, I don't see how that makes the second color picker better than the others. On the contrary, the second design mixes the hue and tint into the same color wheel, so that if the user decides, say, that they want *this* green, but a little lighter, they'll have to guesstimate where on the wheel that will be and try aim their mouse carefully to avoid changing the hue too. The last two designs seem a lot more usable to me in that respect. (They're also direction-neutral.)

Comment: Don't forget CMYK values if there's going to be printing involved.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, that's why I said "if they're not graphic designers". I'm assuming the average user won't have a set hue in mind but would rather play around with the colours in a way that makes sense to them (pick colour, go lighter/darker).

Comment: Yeah, but the slider in the second color picker only goes darker; you can't use it to lighten a color, or tone it with gray.

Comment: I would allow HSL/V colours instead of RGB. HSL/V makes a lot more sense to me, and you've already got RGB in hexadecimal, so I don't think there's much point in also showing it in decimal.

Comment: @Toothbrush A lot of people don't know what hexadecimal notation means, and transforming between hex and RBG is difficult even if you are used to it.

Comment: Small note, Japanese UI's are almost always read left-to-right on computers.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_language_and_computers#Direction_of_text

Comment: @Darkhogg True. That's why I suggested providing HSL/V values instead of RGB, and everyone is happy: those who know RGB HEX can use that, and everyone else uses HSL/V. If you know RGB in decimal, then it would be safe to assume you know it in hexadecimal (in most cases; the Windows colour picker does not give the RGB colour in hexadecimal, but it does give it in HSL).

Comment: @A.Sim: "I'm assuming the average user won't have a set hue in mind but would rather play around with the colours in a way that makes sense to them (pick colour" - which is exactly the moment as of which they have a set hue in mind. At least if they pick several shades of the same colour, the hue might be a bit off, and the result might look slightly unprofessional. The average user might not bother too much - but is that a good excuse? IMHO, a good user interface helps the average user produce a professional-looking result *despite* their slight lack of interest in the details.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, you're right, but having a page look professional after picking colours for it is a matter of graphic design rather than colour-picking technology! All we can do is help the users pick the colour they want.

Comment: If you worry about left/right reading direction -- why not put the slider *below* the wheel? I'm not familiar with any common bottom-to-top reading cultures.

Comment: #007BAD? What do you have against James Bond?!

Answer (score 20):

All the color pickers you list are based on variations of the [HSL / HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) (hue, saturation, lightness / value) color representations.  Thus, their main differences are not in color theory, but simply in the placement and shape of the controls.

That said, the second color picker in your list has one major disadvantage compared to the others: it doesn't have the hue axis separate from the others.  Whereas all the other interfaces allow you to first choose a specific [hue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue) and then pick different [tints and shades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tints_and_shades) of that hue without affecting the base hue, the second color picker combines the saturation and the hue axes in the same color wheel, so that clicking the wheel will alter both the saturation and the hue.

Thus, trying to tint a color while maintaining the hue becomes a tricky exercise in visual acuity and hand-eye-mouse coordination.  Since tinting and shading is a very common thing to do when working with colors and graphics, this could easily get very frustrating.

The first color picker in your list *does* have a separate hue axis, but it's compressed into a fairly small space, making it hard to accurately pick a specific desired hue just by clicking the range.  It also fails to visually represent the circular nature of the hue axis, introducing an arbitrary discontinuity in the red part of the spectrum.  Thus, I'd rate it as the second worst of the lot.

The last two color pickers are very similar in appearance and usability.  I'd personally consider the last one a bit more natural and elegant, since the tint/shade space *is* fundamentally triangular in nature (consisting of combinations of three "pure" shades: black, white, and the pure saturated hue).  That said, I don't see a practical usability difference between them.

Thus, I'd personally rate your color pickers in the following order: #4 (best), #3 (almost equal to #4), #1, #2 (worst).

---

Finally, I'd like to note that *all* the color pickers you've shown share a common flaw: since the HSL / HSV color models they're based on are simple reparametrizations of the RGB color space, which is not perceptually uniform, changing the hue affects the perceived lightness of the color.  (You can easily see this by looking at the color wheels: the blue parts look a *lot* darker than the green and yellow parts.)  Thus, while most of them make it easy to pick different tints and shades of the same hue, the converse — changing the hue of a color while maintaining the same perceived lightness and saturation — is quite difficult.

Alas, I'm not aware of any commonly used color picker designs that would avoid this issue, and there are some fundamental difficulties involved: if you e.g. start by picking a bright green color, and then try to change the hue to, say, blue, you'll find that it's *not* possible without either tinting or shading the color — a normal RGB monitor just can't produce a saturated blue with the same brightness as a saturated green, nor can standard RGB color spaces represent one.  Thus, *some* kind of a compromise would have to be made in such cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think @A. Sim is pretty accurate about what he said in the second paragraph. What do you think about that? Also, with whichever design I go with, I do plan on having a slider for rgb, hsv etc.

Comment: Replied below A. Sim's answer, since I feel it belongs there.

Comment: My personal opinion:  I shudder when I see #4 as it doesn't map to my mindset; I don't know if I should/could rotate the triangle.  Option #1 makes it pretty obvious that I pick a color from the "rainbow" on the right, then fine-tune lightness/darkness from the middle.  And I also like the ability of text box inputs at the bottom mentioned by @plainclothes for folks who know what RGB or HSV values to use if they have a design standard to match.

Answer (score 14):

@DavidGrinberg has a good point about most users not caring about having more than a small number of colors to choose from.  However you can cater to both that group and people who want more choices with an interface supporting progressive enhancement.

Microsoft's provided one with Windows for many years.  I had trouble finding newer screenshots in English; but the look and feel is the same at least through W7.  For a greenfield design I'd probably reduce the total number or standard colors and hide the custom colors section on the small version unless the user had already defined at least one custom color.

[image: http://www.functionx.com/dlgboxes/color1.gif]

[image]

Comment: How I miss those color pickers.

Comment: The only improvement I'd make is the ability to enter HEX and HSM colors as a single string instead of separate values but this was a pretty solid effort by the Microsoft team!

Answer (score 6):

If the user can select different colours for different elements, consider giving them a list of pre-defined palettes to choose from instead - reduces fiddly user interaction and the possibility of migraine inducing yellow and purple colour schemes

http://colorbrewer2.org/# ColorBrewer has such a list of palettes, in this case specifically for data visualisation, but there'll be others out there if these aren't suitable

Comment: I agree themes / palettes is a good option, but this is only the 80% solution (well, closer to 95% percent, but 'the 95% solution' is not a saying). There are always those users, like myself, that are not completely satisfied with the default themes and feel the need to customize it to perfection. For these users, you still should have a color chooser. However, this changes your demographic, and the style of chooser would also change.

Answer (score 5):

Several answers here propose pickers with separate numeric controls for RGB/HSL. These controls are good to have, but not very visual and require some trial-and-error to operate. Below is a picture with dual-mode visual+numeric controls for RGB/HSL depicted on the right.

When you operate one of the sliders, the gradient on the others should change. This gives six dimensions of visual support for changing the color, as opposed to one or two in other pickers (the pickers generally have three dimensions, but only one or two of them are painted with the color being operated).

You can include them with any other picker type, space permitting, but it might work best with some sort of palette and a list of recently picked colors.

[image: Absolute Color Picker example]
<sub>(source: [eltima.com](http://www.eltima.com/images/screenshots/free-color-picker/color_grabber.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I like this approach for a power user's palette builder, but that's a lot to take in for an average user who just wants to pick a nice color.

Comment: The brightness slider `B` appears twice, though, once horizontal and once vertical.

Comment: @Crissov Yep. As you can see on [screenshots](http://tinyurl.com/absolute-color-picker), sometimes there is no vertical bar and sometimes there are one or two. Not sure why they are there, probably they belong to "any color picker" part of "any color picker + extra controls".

Answer (score 5):

Here are two ideas that are not complete proposals, just very rough sketches.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgAjIb.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

### Left mockup

A hue-saturation-lightness/brightness/value/intensity/… representation of an RGB color space cube results in either (typically) a cylinder, a “hexalinder” (prism/cylinder with hexagon base), a hexagonal bipyramid or a sphere. For both kinds of bases, a disc or a hexagon, the plain coordinates can be specified by a combination of the red–cyan, green–magenta and blue–yellow axes. (It’s a flattened cube.) This combines angular hue and the radial saturation. The brightness, lightness or value, i.e. the height, is specified by the white–black axis.

[image: HSL cylinder]

### Right mockup

Many HSB/HSL/HSV/HSI pickers don’t make the connection between visual selection and numeric values obvious. This sketch tries to show a way how this could be achieved.

Remember that this is an input widget so the output/export values are of secondary concern. Still, some people will want to start with a color that they know some numeric representation of: That’s what the tabs and numeric inputs are for and pasting would also work, of course.

Comment: This is a great solution for color theory aware users (like a pro-level design application). It's a very similar approach to the palette creation tools I've used over the years. But that's a complicated presentation for anyone else.

Comment: Nice cylinder solution. I suspect it would be hard as hell to choose the right color there, but nonetheless upvoting for creativity.

Answer (score 3):

[image][image]

Not complete as it is lacking the ability to use hex, enter the channels separately and also to remember colors.

It has :

- Large stripes for better selection
- One for hues
- One for a gradient towards gray, varying saturation
- One for a gradient between white and black, varying value
- A large field to preview
- The option to vary the stroke color toward the background color
- A reset to black&white button

It is rather slim, so not really a Color Dialog but a Color Picker Tool.

Comment: Why is the hue spectrum split at the yellows instead of the reds? That looks so weird.

Comment: It is unusual but I felt that the split between yellow-green and yellow-orange is the most important one. I guess I could make the spectrum moveable..and obviously making it zoomable would be nice as well, as long as it is simple to recognize..

Comment: That's an interesting idea, maybe the spectrum could be dragged up/down and the center is the selected part. But that's probably pretty counter-intuitive. But I do like the zoom idea for increased accuracy! That would also be useful on a standard hue and square saturation/brightness picker, perhaps with the scroll wheel.